# Transposing columns in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a data table that contains the data like below.

[image]

I want to display it in my Grid View like Following. It is actually the transpose of above table and one additional Row added for Viewing Product Details that will be a link button. 
Can you please help me how can I achieve the following requirement in ASP.net using C#.

[image]

Many Thanks,
Awais Afzal.

Comment: Having a `pivot` sql query and output that into datagridview could be one way :) Here is [another way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080734/how-to-generate-a-pivot-datagridview-in-winforms-and-entityframework).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you table is a `DataTable`, you could use such an extension to reorder it:

```
public static DataTable Pivot(this DataTable tbl)
{ 
    var tblPivot = new DataTable();
    tblPivot.Columns.Add(tbl.Columns[0].ColumnName);
    for (int i = 1; i < tbl.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        tblPivot.Columns.Add(Convert.ToString(i));
    }
    for (int col = 0; col < tbl.Columns.Count; col++)
    {
        var r = tblPivot.NewRow();
        r[0] = tbl.Columns[col].ToString();
        for (int j = 1; j < tbl.Rows.Count; j++)
            r[j] = tbl.Rows[j][col];

        tblPivot.Rows.Add(r);
    }
    return tblPivot;
}
```

and set it as new `DataSource`:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = oldDataTable.Pivot();
```

Comment: Thanks Tim but here i have a question that how can i add the last row in the grid view for viewing whole product details. i want to put image button in each column of last row.

Comment: @user1262790: That's a different question. You could use the GridView's `Footer-Row` with appropriate `TemplateFields` containing the `Button`s. Remember to set `ShowFooter=True`.

Comment: could you please give me the hint as in each column of Footer-Row i need product id as i want to display a popup window containing product details on clicking the detail button.

Comment: @TimSchmelter first loop should start from ZERO.