# Transposing columns in RadGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview

Here is the image of a datasource:

[image]

As you see the columns are horizontally arranged and in every row wee see a record data.
The data source is a list of class, I need to swap the rows and columns like this:

[image: d]

as you see the records are showing vertically. How to achieve such this using Telerin RadGridView in winForms?

Comment: This have nothing to do with RadGridView or other winforms control. Convert datasource into collection of transposed objects, then display it with RadGridView as usual datasource.

Comment: @Fabio I know it is not related to the control, but why Am I using a grid component instead of the default one? Because I'm looking for some extra abilities which can not find in normal controls ;)

Comment: You don't need to look for other controls. You need to convert your data

Answer (score 0):

RadGridView does not support the transpose feature because such a functionality would require changing the RadGridView layouts quite a bit, which is not a trivial task. Currently, it is not scheduled. I would suggest you to manually transpose the data and then use it as a data source for the grid. More information can be found on the following pages:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44274/Transpose-a-DataTable-using-C

[Transposing columns in GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919969/transposing-columns-in-gridview)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9011dce9-2ab7-476f-9a79-99df0212b8ee/simplest-way-to-transpose-a-datagridview-in-another-windows-form-in-c?forum=winforms

I hope this information helps.